# Why does my multi-leveled hash print the way I expect?

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

Here's the code and its not working, What I am trying to do is to pass Hash of Hashes to subroutine aka function, but it gives some odd output.

```
my %file_attachments = (
         'test1.zip'  => { 'price' => '10.00', 'desc' => 'the 1st test'},
         'test2.zip'  => { 'price' => '12.00', 'desc' => 'the 2nd test'},
         'test3.zip'  => { 'price' => '13.00', 'desc' => 'the 3rd test'},
         'test4.zip'  => { 'price' => '14.00', 'desc' => 'the 4th test'}
                   );

                   my $a="test5.zip";
                   my $b="the 5th test";

         $file_attachments{$a}->{'price'} = '18.00';
         $file_attachments{$a}->{'desc'} =$b;


        print(%file_attachments);


sub print{

my %file =@_;

foreach my $line (keys %file) {
        print "$line: \n";
         foreach my $elem (keys %{$file{$line}}) {
          print "  $elem: " . $file{$line}->{$elem} . "\n";
    }
                 }
```

OUTPUT::::

```
      test2.zipHASH(0x3a9c6c)test5.zipHASH(0x1c8b17c)test3.zipHASH(0x1c8b3dc)test1.zipHASH(0x3a9b1c)test4.zipHASH(0x1c8b5dc)
```

Answer (score 8):

[perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic) can be a handy tool in debugging Perl code:

```
perlcritic -1 my_code.pl

Subroutine name is a homonym for builtin function at line 24, column 1.  See page 177 of PBP.  (Severity: 4)
```

This is an automated way of discovering what others have stated: that `print` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 4):

`print` is a builtin function; to call a subroutine named that, use `&print(...)` instead of `print(...)`.

Comment: Does that work for `&if(...)`? To my horror--*yes it does!* Even with *strict* `sub if { say 'If!'; }` *works!* Perl is the "new" PL/I!!

Comment: `&if` is just a variable that holds a function type. Are you horrified that you can use `$if`, `@if`, and `%if`?

Comment: `*{""} = sub {print "empty string"};  &{""}()`

Comment: @mob, not really horrified at `&if`--as I wouldn't be at `$if` or the like--but that I can create it with `sub if {...}`. But as ysth shows `*{''}` can be a sub

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you are calling `print` to your subroutine, and print is already defined in perl.

Try changing the name of the subrutine, for instance, this works for me:

```
my %file_attachments = (
         'test1.zip'  => { 'price' => '10.00', 'desc' => 'the 1st test'},
         'test2.zip'  => { 'price' => '12.00', 'desc' => 'the 2nd test'},
         'test3.zip'  => { 'price' => '13.00', 'desc' => 'the 3rd test'},
         'test4.zip'  => { 'price' => '14.00', 'desc' => 'the 4th test'}
                   );

                   my $a="test5.zip";
                   my $b="the 5th test";

         $file_attachments{$a}->{'price'} = '18.00';
         $file_attachments{$a}->{'desc'} =$b;


        printtest(%file_attachments);


sub printtest{

my %file =@_;

foreach my $line (keys %file) {
        print "$line: \n";
         foreach my $elem (keys %{$file{$line}}) {
          print "  $elem: " . $file{$line}->{$elem} . "\n";
    }
                 }
}
```